# Rake task will not send Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am setting up a `rake task`, so I can run it through `heroku scheduler` when it is in production.

The email sends when I run `TaskMailer.task_overdue.deliver_later` elsewhere, and I can see from what is printed on the console that the rake task is reaching the right places.

Can anyone help me with why `action::mailer` is not sending the email when called through a `rake task`

`scheduler.rake:`

```
task :overdue_meeting => :environment do
  MeetingsController.send_reminder
end
```

`meetings_controller.rb:`

```
class MeetingsController < ApplicationController
  def self.send_reminder
    puts "you made it to the send reminder method"
    TaskMailer.task_overdue.deliver_later
    puts "Now sending you over to the task mailer"
  end
end
```

`task_mailer.rb`

```
class TaskMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def task_overdue
    mail(
      from: "info@mysite.com",
      to: "redacted@gmail.com",
      subject: "All sent from rake"
    )
  end
end
```

`task_overdue.html.erb`

```
<h1>Meeting overdue email</h1>

<p>When the method is written, this will enclude all overdue meetings</p>
```

When I run `rake overdue_meeting` on the `console`

> you made it to the send reminder method
>
> Now sending you over to the task mailer

Comment: `deliver_later` delivers later by putting it in the ActiveJob queue to be handled later. ActiveJob requires some sort of backend to run the jobs. Do you have that set up? See [Active Job Basics](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html).

Comment: Great catch @Schwern. I haven't set up ActiveJob queue yet. Changing the syntax to `deliver_now` made it work. Thank you